# Changing field type from check box to radio button in _form.html.erb (Ruby on Rails 3)

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am trying to change check_box field to a radio_button field in order to replace true/false value by enumeration. The scaffold generated code was as following:

```
<!%= f.label :status %><br />
<!%= f.check_box :status %>
```

And I tried to replace it by this:

```
<%= f.radio_button 'status', '0' %><%= f.label :status ,'Public' %><br />
<%= f.radio_button 'status', '1' %><%= f.label :status ,'Protected' %><br />
<%= f.radio_button 'status', '2' %><%= f.label :status ,'Private' %>
```

In MySQL the 'status' field is a tinyint(1), so from DB type perspective it should be ok. However, the evaluation of the fields on the show.html is still true/false and not the expected values - 0,1,2.

I think that this field is configured as a check_box somewhere else in the configurations or code done by Rails, but where is it? Is it possible at all to make such changes? If it is not then what is another painless way to do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tinyint(1) maps to a boolean in rails.

http://www.ruby-forum.com/topic/201859

You should create a migration and change the field to an integer if you wish to use it as an integer.

```
change_column :my_table, :status, :integer
```